# .Net & JQuery - Cross-Page postback of part of a page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, postback, cross-page-posting

I am wondering if there is a way to perform a cross page postback while maintaining the source event and viewstate.  Below is a longer explanation.

I have a page (Control.aspx) where I am loading templates/controls based on query string parameters.  I access this page through a JQuery AJAX GET request to render this template/control inside a container on another page (Default.aspx).  Because of this, I can end up having Control1, Control2, and Control3 all on `Default.aspx`.  I would like the buttons of Control1 to post back to `Control.aspx?id=1`, the buttons of Control2 to post back to `Control.aspx?id=2` and so on, and I want events to be fired as they would normally.  I don't have access to the controls contained on the Control.aspx page except when they are rendered on Default.aspx.  I also have to avoid iframes because of their inability to scroll cleanly on mobile safari.  I can give more detailed information if it's needed.  Thanks for any help you can provide.